# Passing Headers while using Browser Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, http-headers, android-webview

I want to pass some headers while opening a web page. Right now, I'm doing something like :
`browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(data.link));
startActivity(browserIntent`);

Now I'm stuck as I dont know how to pass headers using browserIntent. I've tried using browserIntent.putExtra() but it doesn't work.

Can anyone please help.!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was my biggest question in the last 2days, too! And I found it!!!

I have a Map object that I stored header information. Then the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
if(mExtraHeader!=null){
 for(String key: mExtraHeader.keySet()){
  bundle.putString(key, mExtraHeader.get(key));
 }
}
i.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

One problem is...I guess this would only work with the default browser and other browsers wouldn't have Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS I suppose. Resource: http://gitorious.org/rowboat/packages-apps-browser/blobs/a563d09392905140893d7a017dd63721577e1953/src/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java

Comment: My latest Tests with Chrome 50 on Android 6.0.1 worked fine with EXTRA_HEADERS.

Comment: It was working with chrome 57 for me. but I updated my chrome to 61 and now it is not working!!  :|

Comment: @Mansour did you find out how to solve this problem?

Comment: @DmilaRam No I didn't. I found in some forums that this is a bug. As chrome only accepts one header with this method, I solved my problem by concat all headers to one and send the result as the only header, of course this changes applied on the server too and I think this is not a standard solution. In cases which you develop only the client side, I don't know what you should do!

Answer (score 2):

As Satoshi guessed, this doesn't work with Chrome. If you need to pass headers, you'll need to create your own WebView and load the url with a map of headers. Assume that mWebView is a reference to your webview.

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("referer", "http://some-referer");
mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl, headers);
```