# chrome ignores included header in intent

Tags: android, google-chrome

i used to add header to intent as below:

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(baseUrl));
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        TokenManager manager = TokenManager.getTokenManager();
        bundle.putString("Authorization", manager.getAuthorization());
        bundle.putString("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        myIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
        mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

but it seems it does not work on newest version of google chrome. it ignores headers as there is no header hence i encounter with authorization problem.
can anybody help me? ( i need to use intent not webview )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750361/passing-headers-while-using-browser-intent Accepted answer should work

Comment: @Xirate the accepted answer is the approache that i was using so far (as you can see in question description), its not working with latest google chrome browser, even if its the default browser.

Answer (score -2):

**Try this solution**

I have a Map object that I stored header information. Then the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
if(mExtraHeader!=null){
 for(String key: mExtraHeader.keySet()){
  bundle.putString(key, mExtraHeader.get(key));
 }
}
i.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: your suggestion is just another way to populate the bundle which will be added to the intent with Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS key value, chrome does not read this bundle and hence it does not set headers which we specified. hence we encounter with the problem i mentioned.

Comment: please check this link might be it help to you,

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents#example

Comment: Instead, send your string values directly over Intent. Avoid bundle and check what will happen. or check 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750361/passing-headers-while-using-browser-intent?noredirect=1&lq=1